# Max Voltage of a Coaxial Cable

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric

I have a coaxial cable with an inner radius *a* and an outer cylindrical conducting sheath of radius *b*. The space between them is filled with insulating material with dielectric constant $(1+\chi_e)=\epsilon_r$ and dielectric strength $E_{max}$. I need to derive an expression for the maximum voltage difference that can be applied to the wire before the dielectric breaks down.
I think I need to find the electric field generated by the cable first by finding the electric Displacement, **D**, and then find the voltage difference. But I'm confused on which equations to use or if I'm even thinking about it correctly.

My attempt at a solution is the following:

I first found the Electric displacement $\textbf{D}$
$$
\oint \textbf{D} \cdot d\vec{a} = \textbf{D} 2\pi rl=Q
$$
$$
\textbf{D}=\frac{Q}{2\pi rl}
$$
Then, the relationship between **D** and **E** is $\textbf{D}=\epsilon \textbf{E} $.
We know that the dielectric constant is $\epsilon_{r}=\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon_{0}}=1+\chi_{e}$ so $\epsilon=\epsilon_{0}(1+\chi_{e})$. From this we get
$$\textbf{E}=\frac{\textbf{D}
}{\epsilon}=\frac{Q}{2\pi l \epsilon_{0}(1+\chi_{e})} \frac{1}{r} \hat{r}$$

Here, we can multiply by $\frac{a}{a}$ since $E_{max}$ occurs at $r=a$ so that we can say that $E_{max}=\frac{Q}{2 \pi a l \epsilon_{0}}$ so we can  simplify the expression as follows
$$\textbf{E}=\frac{a\cdot Q}{a \cdot2\pi l \epsilon_{0}(1+\chi_{e})}\frac{1}{r} \hat{r}=\frac{E_{max}\cdot a}{(1+\chi_{0})} \frac{1}{r} \hat{r}$$

Now that we know $\textbf{E}$ we can attempt to find $\textbf{V}$ and with it $V_{max}$.
$$
\textbf{V}=-\int_{a}^{b}\textbf{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$$

So
$$
V_{max}=-\frac{E_{max}\cdot a}{(1+\chi_{0})} \int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{r} dr= \frac{1}{(1+\chi_{e})} \cdot E
_{max}\cdot a\ln{\left( \frac{b}{a} \right)}
$$

I am not entirely sure that this is correct but I'm not sure what is wrong

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to set up and solve the problem

Comment: Ok, for posts, like this one, asking for a full explicit solution to a problem, we require the author to show what they've tried and identify a specific area where they need help. Please see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information about how to ask good questions for this site.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question including my attempt at a solution

Comment: Your final expression has the right dimensions and reasonable scaling with $a$ and $b$. Why do you think it's wrong?